# (Node Js) npm install body-parser: npm Warn expressapp@1.0.0 No description

Tags: node.js, npm

I decided to install `body-parser` and I get the following warnings:

> `npm WARN expressapp@1.0.0 No description`
>
> `npm WARN expressapp@1.0.0 No repository field.`
>
> `npm WARN expressapp@1.0.0 No license field.`

What is it?

I read that I have to change something in `package.json`, but what and is it right?

HELP!!! What I must do?

Comment: These are just warnings. You can ignore them.

Comment: It's unimportant. NPM is just very noisy. Fill the fields in as it makes sense as top level properties in your `package.json` file. An IDE like VS Code can help.

Answer (score 1):

The warnings aren't critical to running the application. In other words, they aren't errors. However, if you wish to no longer receive these warnings then in your `package.json` add the fields listed in the warning:

```
{
  "description": "<add a description of your package>",
  "repository" :
    { 
      "type" : "git", 
      "url" : "<url to github repository>"
    },
  "license" : "BSD-3-Clause"
}
```

Note: I used `"BSD-3-Clause"` as an example, you may wish to use a different license.

Options are available [in the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#license)

References:

- [npm `package.json` description field](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#description-1)
- [npm `package.json` repository field](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#repository)
- [npm `package.json` license field](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#license)